# Timeline of comprehensive NIPA revisions

Tags: macroeconomics, data-request, gdp

I have been fruitlessly searching for a list of dates of comprehensive National Income and Product Account revisions.  Clues I have found so far: The Bureau of Economic Analysis  website says the 1999 revision was the 11th one, and there have been three more since then - 2003, '09, and '13.

From the Philadelphia Fed's vintage datasets it looks like there were comprehensive revisions in 1975, 1985, 1991, and 1995.  This still leaves several unaccounted-for revisions.  Is there an online source for this information or should I hunt through old print copies of the Survey of Current Business?

Thanks

edited to remove acronyms

Comment: Welcome to the site.  This is an international site, so it is helpful to explain country-specific abbreviations that may not be familiar to everyone, or else link to an explanation as here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Income_and_Product_Accounts

Answer (score 2):

You can read what looks like the entire collection of [back issues of Survey of Current Business on the BEA website](http://www.bea.gov/scb/date_guide.asp) but the old issues seem to be PDFs that are not indexed by the site's search engine. [You can see the 1995 revision discussed there](http://www.bea.gov/scb/pdf/national/nipa/1995/0795od.pdf). This seems to be the [1965](http://www.bea.gov/scb/pdf/1965/0865cont.pdf) and [1980](http://www.bea.gov/scb/pdf/1980/1280cont.pdf) revisions. The seem to have changed the termenology on the major revisions at one point. In 1980 the called it *The National Income and Product Accounts of the United States: An Introduction to the Revised Estimates for 1929-80* instead of *Preview of the Comprehensive Revision
of the National Income and Product Accounts* which they called in since at least 1995.

That still leaves five more still to discover. I set my [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) to download the whole archive and then I'll see if can get anywhere with searching the pdfs.